# Gain of filter high-pass and gain of filter Sallen-Key

Tags: filter, gain, low-pass, high-pass-filter

I can not calculate the gain of these two filters separately. I know the first filter is high pass and the second filter is a Sallen-Key, which is low pass. Could you give me a hand, please?

[image]

For the first filter (high pass):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For the second filter (low-pass):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology ?

Comment: TI has an excellent document: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa024b/sloa024b.pdf

Comment: Surely the passband gains of the filters is unity .So if they are cascaded to give bandpass you would get a gain of one.

Comment: @Autistic I do not want a band pass. I want the gain of each of the filters. They are not cascading.

Comment: @RohatKılıç The filters in this document are slightly different from mine. Mine has no resistance at the negative input of AMPOP on Sallen-Key.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Please! Open the document, go to "3 - Low Pass Circuit". You'll see the gain formula, K = 1+R4/R3, just above Fig.5. Now look at your bottom-most circuit. It's easy to see that R4 = 0 and R3 = infinity, so K = 1 which means **unity gain**. Same thing applies for high-pass circuit.

Comment: I'm confused about the wording of the question now. Do you mean you are unable to calculate the gain of the individual filters? Or you're supposed to calculate the gain of these two circuits combined? If it's the latter case, you need to show how these two circuits are combined.

Comment: @horta What I need is to calculate the gain of the two individual filters.

Comment: Ok, then my answer should suffice. Let me know if anything confuses you about it.

Comment: We know that can't be right because if we take S->infinite you end up with C1/(3C3+2C1) as the gain, but if you look at the circuit, at high frequency all caps are shorts so your output would equal your input.

Comment: @horta What is the end result of the filter? I've changed my calculations.

Comment: My calculations are in my answer, but mine can't be correct either according to the same S-> infinite analysis. Your change in calculations still ends up with C1/(2C3+C1) which doesn't match up with a gain of 1 at infinite.

Comment: @horta You erased when you replace I1 in the equation I1 = I2 + I3. I1 = (Vin-Vmid) / (1 / C1s)

Comment: Good catch, I'll fix that and see what happens.

Comment: you have two voltage sources and transfer function based on impedance(f) ratios from each, input and output.  try again using superposition

Comment: Did the S->infinite analysis on my answer and with some algebra gymnastics, it does come out to 1, so I would say mine is now correct.

Comment: @horta I solved it, too. I'll post my reply in a moment. Could you check if it is equivalent to your response please?

Comment: I'll check it after lunch.

Comment: @horta I already put the answer in the post. Thank you very much if you could check.

Comment: @horta In this step you applied badly the distributive formula for Vout: (Vin-Vmid)/(1/C1s) = (Vmid-Vout)/R2 + (Vmid-Vout)/(1/C3s)
VinC1s = Vmid(1/R2+C1s+C3s) - VoutC3s

Comment: @horta You forgot to multiply the Vout by 1 / R2

Comment: @horta It's all right in my calculations?

Comment: Yup, I've updated my answer and we finally match and S-> infinite equals 1 which checks out. Note that you are saying that the gain at infinite = 1 but the gain at any frequency is the equation you ended up with (which is frequency (s) dependent).

Comment: @horta To calculate the low pass also do I have to do s-> infinity?

Comment: For low-pass, it's just the inverse. S-> infinity, gain = 0. At S->0 gain should be either 1 or whatever base gain there is. In your case, just from inspection, the gain is 1 at 0 frequency because the caps become open circuits and Vin=Vout.

Comment: @horta I've already done the calculations for the low-pass filter. Could you check please? I did not realize how you predicted that the gain of this filter would give 1. I did not realize how you know at the outset that Vin will be equal to Vout. I realized we have to remove the capacitors from the circuit, but I did not realize your deduction.

Comment: The gain of the filter can be deduced at low frequency by removing the caps and then determining how much current will flow from Vin. Since there's no current path from Vin to ground or Vin to Vout, there can be no current flow. If there's no current flow, then regardless of what R1 or R2 are, Vin = V+ = V- = Vout.

Comment: @horta What is V + and V-? I understood the whole explanation except that detail.

Comment: V+ and V- are usually what we use to indicate the positive and negative inputs to the op-amp. I checked your math and it all looks good for the low pass filter.

Comment: @horta Can you help me in my other question, please? My other doubt is about this problem, too. Thanks. The link is: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/299625/sallen-key-filters-projection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gain is Vout/Vin. Using ideal op-amp theory and using impedances calculate Vout/Vin. Capacitances become 1/Cs.

For the high pass filter, you'd get something like this: 
$$I_2 = \frac{V_{mid}-V_{out}}{R_2} $$
$$I_1 = \frac{V_{in}-V_{mid}}{\frac{1}{C_1s}} $$
$$I_3 = \frac{V_{mid}-V_{out}}{\frac{1}{C_3s}}   $$# Vout due to op-amp inputs being equal.
$$I_4 = \frac{V_{out}}{R_4}                $$
$$I_1 = I_2 + I_3  $$
$$ I_3 = I_4  $$
Using the info above, you should now be able to solve for Vout/Vin which is your gain. Repeat the same thing for the next filter.

Using I3=I4:
$$\frac{V_{out}}{R_4} = \frac{V_{mid}-V_{out}}{\frac{1}{C_3s}}  $$
$$V_{out} = (V_{mid} - V_{out})R_4C_3s $$
$$V_{out}(1+R_4C_3s) = V_{mid}R_4C_3s   $$
$$V_{out} = V_{mid}R_4C_3s/(1+R_4C_3s)  $$
$$V_{mid} = V_{out}(1+R_4C_3s)/(R_4C_3s)  $$

Using I1 = I2 +I3:
$$\frac{V_{in}-V_{mid}}{\frac{1}{C_1s}} = \frac{V_{mid}-V_{out}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{mid}-V_{out}}{\frac{1}{C_3s}}  $$
$$V_{in}C_1s = V_{mid}(\frac{1}{R_2}+C_1s+C_3s) - V_{out}(C_3s +\frac{1}{R_2})$$
$$V_{mid} = \frac{V_{in}C_1s + V_{out}(C_3s+\frac{1}{R_2})}{\frac{1}{R_2}+C_1s+C_3s}  $$

Combine top and bottom equations:
$$V_{out}\frac{1+R_4C_3s}{R_4C_3s} = \frac{V_{in}C_1s + V_{out}(C_3s+1/R_2)}{1/R_2+C_1s+C_3s}  $$
$$V_{out}( \frac{1}{R_4C_3s} +1 -\frac{C_3s+1/R_2}{1/R_2+C_1s+C_3s} ) = V_{in}\frac{C_1s}{1/R_2+C_1s+C_3s}  $$
$$Gain = \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{ \frac{C_1s}{1/R_2+C_1s+C_3s} } { \frac{1}{R_4C_3s} +1 -\frac{C_3s+1/R_2}{1/R_2+C_1s+C_3s} }  $$

$$\frac{\frac{C_1s(R_4C_3s)}{X}} {1+R_4C_3s-R_4C_3s\frac{C_3s+1/R_2}{X} }   $$

$$ \frac{ C_1s(R_4C_3s)  }{ X+(R_4C_3s)X-R_4C_3s(C_3s+1/R_2) } $$

$$ \frac{C_1sR_4C_3s  }{  (1/R_2+C_1s+C_3s)(1+R_4C_3s)-R_4C_3s(C_3s+1/R_2) } $$
$$ \frac{C_1sR_4C_3s }{ 1/R_2+C_1s+C_3s + R_4C_3s/R_2 + C_1sR_4C_3s+R_4C_3^2s^2-R_4C_3^2s^2-R_4C_3s/R_2 } $$
$$ \frac{ C_1sR_4C_3s  }{1/R_2+C_1s+C_3s + C_1sR_4C_3s } $$
$$\frac {R_4C_1C_3s^2}{R_4C_1C_3s^2 + (C_1+C_3)s + 1/R_2 }$$

I don't guarantee I didn't make a typo somewhere, but this should put you on the right track. Once you determine the basic currents/voltages, it's like any other circuit where it's just a lot of algebra.

Comment: Please consider using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your answer more readable. Note EE.SE uses `\$` to start and end inline Mathjax, rather than just `$`. Display equations still start and end with `$$`.

Comment: @ThePhoton Done.

Answer (score 2):

Each filter is a Sallen Key unity gain filter.

You can tell they're unity gain from the direct feedback between the op-amp output and the inverting input, which configures the op-amp for unity gain operation.

The top one is highpass. The bottom one is lowpass.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calculating the DC gain of the filters... then that's pretty simple.

Capacitors are open-circuits (disconnected) at DC. From there, we see that we have only R1 + R2 into the "Plus" terminal of the OpAmp (so there's a voltage divider between the internal "input impedance"), and we have the output shorted to the negative feedback terminal.

So it should be something close to a unity-gain amplifier at DC.

---

For the high-pass filter, the capacitors are shorts at infinite frequency. Follow the logic again, and we see that the OpAmp is once again a unity-gain amplifier at infinite frequency.

In practice, this isn't the case because all OpAmps are bandwidth limited... but assuming "perfect theoretical components", that's how you do things.